# Why does Rust have mutexes and other sychronization primitives, if sharing of mutable state between tasks is not allowed?

Tags: rust

My understanding is that it's not possible to share mutable state between tasks in Rust, so why does Rust has things like [mutexes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) in the language?  What's their purpose?

Comment: I think you might be laboring under some invalid assumptions.  It says right in the page you linked that a Mutex is "A mutual exclusion primitive useful for protecting *shared data*"

Comment: Everything I've seen though indicates that there is no shared mutable state between tasks though, it's all done via message passing.  So either there _is_ shared state capability and I can't find any info on it anywhere, or these primitives aren't useful for anything.

Comment: Is it possible that the message passing requires synchronization?

Comment: In fact the official [FAQ](https://github.com/graydon/rust/wiki/Doc-language-FAQ) says explicitly: "Mutability control. Immutable by default. No shared mutable state across tasks."

Comment: *by default* being the operative words, there.  It is an intriguing question, though.

Comment: That doesn't pertain to the third sentence though.  That just means that variable declarations are by default the equivalent of const in C.

Comment: @gct: `Mutex` and other such things are safe abstractions over the unsafe behaviour of sharing mutable state across tasks. The language itself does not support mutable state.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Why does it have the `mut` keyword then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: sorry, I meant *shared* mutable state.

Answer (score 18):

"Sharing mutable data between tasks is not allowed" is an oversimplification. No offense meant, it's also used in much introductory material on Rust, and for good reasons. But the truth is, Rust just wants to get rid of data races; not sharing anything is the preferred approach but not the only. Rust also wants to be a system programming language in the same sense as C and C++ are, so it won't nilly-willy *completely* remove some capability or performance optimization. However, in general shared mutable memory is not safe (data races etc.) so if you want it, you will have to acknowledge the responsibility by wrapping it in `unsafe` blocks.

Luckily, some patterns of using shared mutable memory *are* safe (e.g. using proper locking discipline). When these patterns are recognized and considered important enough, someone writes some `unsafe` code that they convince themselves (or perhaps even "prove") exposes a safe *interface*. In other words: Code using the interface can never violate the various safety requirements of Rust. For example, while `Mutex` allows you to access mutable memory from different tasks at different times, it never permits *aliasing* among tasks (i.e. access at the same time), so data races are prevented.

Answer (score 7):

Rust defines a `Mutex` as

> A mutual exclusion primitive useful for protecting shared data

A clear example of `Mutex` use can be found [in the `Mutex` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).  Note the use of the `mut` keyword to designate mutable variables:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

const N: usize = 10;

// Spawn a few threads to increment a shared variable (non-atomically), and
// let the main thread know once all increments are done.
//
// Here we're using an Arc to share memory among threads, and the data inside
// the Arc is protected with a mutex.
let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

let (tx, rx) = channel();
for _ in 0..10 {
    let (data, tx) = (data.clone(), tx.clone());
    thread::spawn(move || {
        // The shared state can only be accessed once the lock is held.
        // Our non-atomic increment is safe because we're the only thread
        // which can access the shared state when the lock is held.
        //
        // We unwrap() the return value to assert that we are not expecting
        // threads to ever fail while holding the lock.
        let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
        *data += 1;
        if *data == N {
            tx.send(()).unwrap();
        }
        // the lock is unlocked here when `data` goes out of scope.
    });
}

rx.recv().unwrap();
```

Rust also provides an [`unsafe` keyword](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/reference.html#unsafety).  Unsafe operations are those that potentially violate the memory-safety guarantees of Rust's static semantics. So the guarantee of immutable safety is by no means assured.