# How can I mutably share an i32 between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm new to Rust and threading and I'm trying to print out a number while adding to it in another thread. How can I accomplish this?

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut num = 5;
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            num += 1;
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
        }
    });
    output(num);
}

fn output(num: i32) {
    loop {
        println!("{:?}", num);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work: it always prints `5` as if the number is never incremented.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please read the ["Shared-State Concurrency" chapter of The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html), it explains how to do this in detail.

In short:

1. Your program does not work because `num` is **copied**, so `output()` and the thread operate on different copies of the number. The Rust compiler will fail to compile with an error if `num` is not copyable.
2. Since you need to share the same variable between multiple threads, you need to wrap it in an [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) (**a**tomic **r**eference-**c**ounted variable)
3. Since you need to modify the variable inside the `Arc`, you need to put it in a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html). You use the `.lock()` method to obtain a mutable reference out of a `Mutex`. The method will ensure exclusive access across the whole process during the lifetime of that mutable reference.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let num = Arc::new(Mutex::new(5));
    // allow `num` to be shared across threads (Arc) and modified
    // (Mutex) safely without a data race.

    let num_clone = num.clone();
    // create a cloned reference before moving `num` into the thread.

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            *num.lock().unwrap() += 1;
            // modify the number.
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
        }
    });

    output(num_clone);
}

fn output(num: Arc<Mutex<i32>>) {
    loop {
        println!("{:?}", *num.lock().unwrap());
        // read the number.
        //  - lock(): obtains a mutable reference; may fail,
        //    thus return a Result
        //  - unwrap(): ignore the error and get the real
        //    reference / cause panic on error.
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}
```

You may also want to read:

- [Why does Rust have mutexes and other sychronization primitives, if sharing of mutable state between tasks is not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350954/why-does-rust-have-mutexes-and-other-sychronization-primitives-if-sharing-of-mu/23361845#23361845)
- [What happens when an Arc is cloned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984932/what-happens-when-an-arc-is-cloned/40985661)
- [How do I share a mutable object between threads using Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/share-mutable-object-between-threads/31373349#31373349) (for why we need `Arc<Mutex<i32>>` instead of `Arc<i32>`)
- [When would you use a Mutex without an Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116317/when-would-you-use-a-mutex-without-an-arc/33116578#33116578) (for why we need `Arc<Mutex<i32>>` instead of `Mutex<i32>`)

Comment: For general types `T`, a `Mutex<T>` is indeed necessary. Another option for some types is to use wrapper types in [`std::sync::atomic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html), for example [`AtomicIsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicIsize.html) which provides methods like `fetch_add` or `compare_and_swap`. (You'll also have to specify what memory ordering to impose.)

Answer (score 9):

The other answer solves the problem for any type, but as pnkfelix [observes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849210/share-i32-mutably-between-threads#comment72817586_42851615), atomic wrapper types are another solution that will work for the specific case of `i32`.

Since Rust 1.0, you can use `AtomicBool`, `AtomicPtr<T>`, `AtomicIsize` and `AtomicUsize` to synchronize multi-threaded access to `bool`, `*mut T`, `isize` and `usize` values. In Rust 1.34, several new `Atomic` types have been stabilized, including `AtomicI32`. (Check the `std::sync::atomic` documentation for the current list.)

Using an atomic type is most likely more efficient than locking a `Mutex` or `RwLock`, but requires more attention to the low-level details of memory ordering. If your threads share more data than can fit in one of the standard atomic types, you probably want a `Mutex` instead of multiple `Atomic`s.

That said, here's a version of kennytm's answer using `AtomicI32` instead of `Mutex<i32>`:

```
use std::sync::{
    atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering},
    Arc,
};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let num = Arc::new(AtomicI32::new(5));
    let num_clone = num.clone();

    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        num.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
    });

    output(num_clone);
}

fn output(num: Arc<AtomicI32>) {
    loop {
        println!("{:?}", num.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}
```

`Arc` is still required for shared ownership (but see [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/3650362)).

Choosing the right memory `Ordering` is far from trivial. `SeqCst` is the most conservative choice, but if there is only one memory address being shared, `Relaxed` should also work. See the links below for more information.

### Links

1. [`std::sync::atomic` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html)
2. [Atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/atomics.html) (chapter of *The Rustonomicon*)
3. [LLVM Memory Model for Concurrent Operations](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#memory-model-for-concurrent-operations) and [Atomic Instructions and Concurrency Guide](https://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html)