# How to use shared memory for a Vec<f64>?

Tags: linux, process, rust, shared-memory

Is there any option to use shared memory for `Vec<f64>` in Rust?

Processes in my program swap two or more values in a `Vec<f64>` and I need the memory to be shared between processes.

Comment: Not relevant to your case, but for those who might accidentally stumble on this question: [How do I pass disjoint slices from a vector to different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33818141/155423); [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423); [How can I mutably share an i32 between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42849210/155423)

Comment: What kind of changes -- do they only mutate items in the `Vec`, or do they add and remove items from the `Vec` itself?

Comment: They swap two or more values in my vector.

Comment: Are we talking shared between *processes* or between *threads*? Threads share memory normally, with processes you have to set it up with system calls and things. It's a lot more difficult.

Comment: Shared memory between processes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to safely create a `Vec` backed by shared memory. There are two reasons this is true:

1. A `Vec` owns its memory and will reallocate it when grown or free it when dropped. Unsafely creating a `Vec` pointing to `mmap`ped memory will corrupt the heap when the `Vec` reallocates or goes out of scope.
2. A `Vec` has exclusive access to its memory, like a `&mut` reference. The compiler is free to omit and reorder reads and writes based on the assumption that nothing else is using the memory. If this assumption is broken, the behavior is undefined. To relax this assumption, your data type needs to be something based on `UnsafeCell`.

`Vec` is the wrong pointer for this job. Try `&[UnsafeCell<f64>]`, or maybe `&[AtomicU64]` (with conversions using `from_bits` and `to_bits`), since there isn't an `AtomicF64` in the standard library.