# Borrowed data escapes outside of associated function

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I'm new to Rust, and trying to learn the language by creating something around it.

Facing this problem that the `self` is valid inside this function but the closure is `async` so it may be executed after the lifetime of this function and that closure captures `self`. I get the problem. But what should I do? I understand that it is something to do with the lifetimes. But can someone point to me what the solution is?

```
pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Result<i32, &str> {
    .
    .
    .

    match server.accept().await {
        Ok(p) => {
            tokio::spawn(async {
                self.handle_temp_connection(p)
            });
        },
        Err(err) => {
            println!("Some problem accepting a connection.")
        }
    }
}

fn handle_temp_connection(&self, p_socket_addr: (TcpStream, SocketAddr)) {
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
  --> src/app.rs:34:21
   |
20 |       pub async fn run(&mut self) -> Result<i32, &str> {
   |                        ---------
   |                        |
   |                        `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
   |                        let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
34 | /                     tokio::spawn(async {
35 | |                         self.handle_temp_connection(p)
36 | |                     });
   | |                      ^
   | |                      |
   | |______________________`self` escapes the associated function body here
   |                        argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Comment: You won't be able to pass `self` along to a thread unless you're prepared to hand over ownership as well. References will not work. Could this be `pub async fn run (self) ...`?

Comment: Okay so what should I do in this case? I want to handle that connection in a another function.

Comment: That's fine so long as you can hand over ownership. This is where using channels to communicate back any results might help.

Comment: Above that `match` there is `let server = self.server.as_ref.unwrap()` So If I use `self` in the function declaration, `self.server` would consume the `self` and I would not be able to use it afterwards.

Comment: So how does production code deal with this problem? Its a general thing I guess, to invoke a thread that can use the caller's self members? How do you achieve it?

Comment: Personally I just architect so that the `self` in question is self-contained and can be delegated, as in handed off entirely. This typically means having a handler per connection rather than a handler for all connections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254662/discussion-between-bradley101-and-tadman).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `handle_temp_connection` is supposed to be an async function. If it's not, you should use `tokio::spawn_blocking`, but most of the rest still applies.

If you only need to call `run` once and nothing else on `self` later, then you can have it take ownership and give ownership to `handle_temp_connection`.

```rs
pub async fn run(self)
...
tokio::spawn(self.handle_temp_connection(p));
...
async fn handle_temp_connection(self, p_socket_addr: (TcpStream, SocketAddr))
```

If you need `self` after calling `run`, you can still pass ownership to `handle_temp_connection`, but after cloning it.

```rs
tokio::spawn(self.clone().handle_temp_connection(p));
```

If you use an async block here, you will need to clone it first into another variable and then `async move` that variable into the block.

If you want some shared state between the `self` in `run` and the `self` in `handle_temp_connection`, then you can use `Arc` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42849210/6274355).

Another thing you can do is rewrite `handle_temp_connection` to not use `self`.

```rs
tokio::spawn(handle_temp_connection(p));
```

If you need some information from `self`, you can clone parts of `self` and pass them to `handle_temp_connection` as arguments.